# Pass multiple parameters through GET method in URL of ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

I want to pass multiple parameters through GET method in URL of ajax call but its not working.any kind help would be appreciated Thankyou

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType: 'json',
            async:true,
            cache: false,

            headers:{ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},

iurl: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins="+dest_lat+"&"+dest_lon+"|"+data[i][3]+"&"+data[i][4],

      success: function(msg) {                                          
                                alert(msg);
                              }

      });
```

Comment: Did you try using the `data:` option of the AJAX call instead of appending them to the url?

Comment: in our case how can i use that DATA:......?????could u plz explain or help in this regard as its my first experience of using ajax!!!

Comment: Did you even try to Google it? From http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, `data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }`

Comment: data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }.....in this each parameter is saved in its seperate variable where as in my api i am using a single variable so how could it be formated??

Comment: origins=41.43206,-81.38992|-33.86748,151.20699                                  like in this manualy lat/longitude are given but we are trying to take them from our MySql database

Comment: Your data is not different from any other data. You can put the whole string together first and store it in a variable and use that in the `data` part or you can use the string the way you are using it in the url. Consider hiring a programmer if this is above your head.